# How to log CPU usage by processes

Tags: windows-server-2003, logging, task-manager

On one of our servers I used Perfmon to log CPU usage.  It showed me several
spikeat 100% but don't know what process(s) caused that.  So, how can I log
CPU usage for process which used more than 40%?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Perfmon, use the "Process" counter container.  You can then examine individual processes.  To dig deeper use SysInternals (now MS) ProcessExplorer.

Answer (score 0):

If you monitor your servers with SNMP, and store the recordings in something like Solarwinds Orion or MRTG or several other systems, you can keep a graph of CPU usage by process. You'll have to be able to keep the data by process name; I don't know if MRTG will do that OOTB or at all. I know that Orion will track named processes.

Answer (score 0):

How about the "tasklist" command? it's actually really useful, try it with the '/v' option.

Oh and [HERE](http://commandwindows.com/tasklist.htm)'s a guide to it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also deploy nagios for monitoring